# I have a vector of pointers to objects. How to free memory?

Tags: c++

For example:

```
class Airport : public vector<Airline*>
```

How do I free the memory properly? I would prefer not use smart pointers as I have not learned it yet in my course.

Comment: A simple rule : never inherit from std classes like vector, set, deque, etc...

Comment: Can you give a little more context? Inheriting from std::vector is far from recommended. Do you have your own vector implementation?

Comment: Without knowing exactly what you're trying to do, it seems more sensible to have the `vector` as a member of `Airport`.

Comment: How are you initializing an instance of the Airport class? How are you adding entries to it? You do realise you can create a std::vector<Airline> quite easily?

Comment: `std::vector` is primarily for composition and not inheritance.

Comment: _"How do I free the memory properly?"_ - that depends on how you allocated it in the first place.

Answer (score 5):

As others have pointed out, `Airport` should not inherit from `vector`. `Airport` should contain a `vector`. Then there is the question of who owns the Airlines, do you want the Airlines to be destroyed when the `Airport` is destroyed? If so I suggest either a simple `std::vector<Airline>`:

```
class Airport {
    std::vector<Airline> airlines_;
    //...
};
```

Or if you need polymorphism, i.e `Airline` is a base class with specializations for different Airlines I suggest smart pointers:

```
class Airport {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Airline>> airlines_; 
    //...
};
```

If you really don't want to use smart pointers you could use raw pointers and then **carefully** delete them in the destructor:

```
class Airport {
    std::vector<Airline*> airlines_;
  public:
    Airport(const Airport&) = delete;             // not allowed
    Airport& operator=(const Airport&); = delete; // not allowed
   ~Airport() { 
        for (auto airline : airlines) {
            delete airline;
        }
    }
   //...
};
```

If you do this you need to think carefully about what copying behaviour you want `Airport` to have because the default copy constructor and assignment operator will not manage the memory properly. As a first step you can prevent copying by 'delete'ing copy constructor and assignment operator as I have above. But I suggest as soon as you learn about smart pointers use them instead as most of these problems go away.

If the Airport does not own the Airlines then store raw pointers or shared smart pointers in the vector and leave it to whoever owns the Airlines to free the memory properly. In my mind an `Airline` can operate in more than one `Airport` so it doesn't make sense for the `Airport` to own the `Airline` so there should be a separate container of `Airline` but it depends on your model.

Comment: `vector` cannot store a reference. You will at least need a `std::reference_wrapper`.

Comment: Also, your `Airport` class with raw pointers violates the Rule of Three/Five and will crash as soon as an object of type `Airport` is assigned to or copied.

Comment: @pmr, the question was about how to free the memory properly, not how to write the whole Airport class, I'll edit it to make it more clear...

Comment: I agree, but just providing a snippet that is in violation of all that is good and proper to a novice comes close to malice ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
class Airport : public vector<Airline*>
```

A vector doesn't have a virtual destructor, so inheriting from it lands you into UB behavior.

Try this instead:

```
class Airport
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Airline>> airlines_; // notice std::unique_ptr
    // ...
};
```

By storing std::unique_ptr instead of raw pointers, you will not have to delete anything explicitly. If (for some reason) you need to store raw pointers, the deleting of the pointers should be done like this:

```
Airport::~Airport() { // declare it in the class
    std::for_each(airlines_.begin(), airlines_.end(),
        std::default_delete<Airline>{});
}
```

Comment: +1 I deleted my answer. Using smart pointers is the best way to solve the problem.

Comment: I suspect it should be a `shared_ptr`. There are many airlines that serve multiple airports ;)

Comment: Quite possible - it would depend on how an Airline instance is meant to be used I guess.

Comment: -1, inheriting from `std::vector` is not undefined behaviour. Definitely not undefined behaviour behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

To start: inheriting from `std::vector` is wrong for technical reasons
(it does not have a virtual destructor). In your case it also seems
wrong for domain reasons: an Airport **is not** a Sequence of
Airlines. Just imagine someone explaining `AirportS` to you in the
real world using those words. You would certainly argue the point.

You have two approaches.

Use values (`std::vector<Airline>`) to circumvent this problem. You
also should define a proper equality operator `operator==(const
Airline&, const Airline&)` if you do this.

or

If `AirportS` are really supposed to store pointers to `AirlineS`, you
need to be aware of ownership. Does an `Airport` really own the
`AirlineS` stored in it? If so, it should delete them at the end of
its life-time. If not, they should life on. In the first case, someone
else needs to take care of storing and destroying `AirlineS`.

If an `Airport` owns and destroys `AirlineS` you need to make sure you
observe the Rule of Three in your implementation.